# Changing File Name in Auto Weekly FTP Download

Tags: batch-file

I have a SCR file with the below commands

```
open myftp.myserver.com
myusername
mypassword
lcd "c:\myfolder"
cd webfolder
get myfile09202012
```

I run this script with a BAT file as a Windows Task once per week.  This week, the file name to download is "myfile09202012".  Next week, the file name would be "myfile09272012".  How would I create a script to auto-generate the new file name every week?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following convention

```
get myfile%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~10%
```

If you type in the command 'echo %date%', you will receive today's date in the format 'Wed 10/10/2012'
The string '%date:~4,2%' returns the above format at the 4th placeholder and returns the next 2 characters.

Answer (score 1):

pipe the output of this batch file to your script file, then run the resulting script in the normal way.

```
@echo off
echo open myftp.myserver.com
echo myusername
echo mypassword
echo lcd "c:\myfolder"
echo cd webfolder
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('echo %date%') do echo get myfile%%a%%b%%c
```

it will use the current date to generate the filename

to incorporate the whole batch within another batch file, it would end up something like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
cd c:\myfolder
echo open myftp.myserver.com > mySCRfile.SCR 
echo myusername >> mySCRfile.SCR 
echo mypassword >> mySCRfile.SCR 
echo lcd "c:\myfolder" >> mySCRfile.SCR 
echo cd webfolder >> mySCRfile.SCR 
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('echo %date%') do echo get myfile%%a%%b%%c >> mySCRfile.SCR 
ftp -s:mySCRfile.SCR
```

or

```
@ECHO OFF
cd c:\myfolder
call MakeTheScr > mySCRfile.SCR 
ftp -s:mySCRfile.SCR
```

Comment: Note that this is locale-specific.  You may need to adjust the delimiters and which tokens you're getting, if your date format is (say) YYYY-MM-DD.

I'd also recommend choosing YYYYMMDD as your naming convention as it makes it easier to go through the history by sorting by filename (i.e., files from 1/2013 will sort after 12/2012 properly).

Comment: So I tried the code but it doesn't auto generate today's date.  It tries to get the file "myfile%%a%%b%%c"

Comment: edited the batch file. the output when I type `test > testoutput.txt` is this: `open myftp.myserver.com ¤ 
myusername ¤ 
mypassword ¤ 
lcd "c:\myfolder" ¤ 
cd webfolder ¤ 
get myfile09242012 ¤ ` (using ¤ to indicate a new line)

Comment: No dice, this is what my BAT file looks like right now @ECHO OFF
cd c:\myfolder
ftp -s:mySCRfile.SCR

Comment: I get an "Invalid command" response with the "for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('echo %date%') do echo get myfile%%a%%b%%c" line.  Can you tell me what "call MakeTheScr > mySCRfile.SCR" is supposed to do?

Comment: the `call` command just executes another file, and the `>` directs its output to the specified file. `MakeTheScr` would be a file called `makethescr.bat` which has all the echo commands in it